# Accessing ScreenTip text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a long MS Word doc that has many bookmarks/hyperlinks.  The only purpose of the bookmarks is to be able to use the screen tips to view additional information about what is bookmarked.

Is there a way to access this screen tip text, and store it in a variable?

Eventually I will use this to create a macro that will change the displayed text to include the screen tip text (so the information can be printed, when necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to print-to-console all the Hyperlink ScreenTips in your document:

```
Sub printScreenTips()
    Dim link As Hyperlink
    For Each link In ThisDocument.Hyperlinks
        Debug.Print link.ScreenTip
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: I'm not aware of a way to add a ScreenTip to a *bookmark*, but you can add a ScreenTip to the hyperlink that points to a bookmark.